# overflow:hidden on position:relative/absolute workaround android 4.1

Tags: android, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

This is my first question, sorry if I made something wrong.

Well I'm trying to create a rounded button that dynamically "fills" according to a parameter. I've created an inner div inside the button, absolute positioned in the bottom. It works perfect on chrome webview, but I cant make it work on android 4.1.

here is how it should look:
[right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaPLh.png) 
and this is how it looks on android 4.1:
[wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qahO.png)
This is my code:

```
<div class="col" style="padding:0px; margin: 0px; text-align:center; height:100%">
  <a  style="overflow:hidden; padding: 0px; height:125px; width:125px; border-radius: 50%; border-width:2px; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.0001); z-index: 2" class="button likebuttons" ng-click="voteClick(1, vote.id, thread.id) " ng-class="{'button-dislike':var==1}">
    <img style="margin:27px ; vertical-align:middle; position:relative; z-index: 1 ; width:60%; height:60%" src="img/thumbs-down.png" align="middle"></img>
    <div style="-webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in; height:{{(thread.get('ratio'))*100}}%; position:absolute; bottom:0; width: 100%;background-color:#db0000"></div>
  </a> </div>
```

The "button" class is position:relative and the other classes just add a different border color.

I've tryed everything I could find with no success...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the block formating context of `<a>` and set it to relative position too:

```html
<div class="col" style="padding:0px; margin: 0px; text-align:center; height:100%">
  <a style="display:inline-block;position:relative;overflow:hidden; padding: 0px; height:125px; width:125px; border-radius: 50%; border-width:2px;border:solid; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.0001); z-index: 2" class="button likebuttons" ng-click="voteClick(1, vote.id, thread.id) "
  ng-class="{'button-dislike':var==1}">
    <img style="margin:27px ; vertical-align:middle; position:relative; z-index: 1 ; width:60%; height:60%" src="img/thumbs-down.png" align="middle"></img>
    <div style="transition: all 0.9s ease-in; height:62.5%; position:absolute; bottom:0; width: 100%;background-color:#db0000"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

added :

```
a {
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
}
```

---

Do not mind the webkit prefixe not needed anymore or use last the non prefixed rules (transition)

Comment: Just tried, same results... Overflow still not working :/..  Ok I'll remove the prefixes.